# Fill shapefile column with raster value, shapefile with alias name and calculated field

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, fields-attributes, ogr

I've to sample raster values to fill a column of point shapefile using Python, and for this I've no problem. But this shapefile has some fields with alias name and some fields that result from an expression.
How can I copy this fields to a new shapefile and then fill the column with raster values?
I have created the new fields and using `SetField` from ogr to copy the values of original shapefile but I can't found a way to set the Alias name and the calculated fields.

This is my code, I'm not a programming expert:

```
def sample(shp,raster):
#open raster 
        rasterfile = raster  
        raster = gdal.Open(rasterfile)  
        gt = raster.GetGeoTransform()  
        banda = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
#open shapfeile  
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')  
        dataset = driver.Open(shp)  
        layer1 = dataset.GetLayer()  
        spatialRef = layer1.GetSpatialRef()  
#create new shapefile
        outputShapefile = shp.split('.')[1] + '_coord_z.shp'
        print(outputShapefile)
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
        new_data = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)  
        layer = new_data.CreateLayer(outputShapefile, spatialRef,ogr.wkbPoint)
#define fields name
        name_field = ogr.FieldDefn('Apparati', ogr.OFTString) 
        name_field.SetWidth(100)
        layer.CreateField(name_field)

        name_field = ogr.FieldDefn('Stato', ogr.OFTString) 
        name_field.SetWidth(15)
        layer.CreateField(name_field)

        name_field = ogr.FieldDefn('coord_Z', ogr.OFTReal) 
        layer.CreateField(name_field)

# sampling raster values        
        for feat in layer1: 
                geom=feat.GetGeometryRef()  
                point=geom.Centroid().ExportToWkt()  
                mx=float(point.split(' ')[1][1:len(point.split(' ')[1])])  
                my=float(point.split(' ')[2][0:len(point.split(' ')[2])-1])  
                px = int((mx-gt[0])/gt[1])
                py = int((my-gt[3])/gt[5])
                intval = banda.ReadAsArray(px,py,1,1) 
                zcoord=float(intval)
                #set layer field's values
                feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
                feature.SetField('Apparati',feat.GetField('Apparati'))
                feature.SetField('Stato',feat.GetField('Stato'))
                feature.SetField('coord_Z',zcoord)
                feature.SetGeometry(geom)
                layer.CreateFeature(feature)
                feature = None
        raster = None
        Dataset = None
        new_data = None
```

I need to add to fields 'Apparati', 'Stato', and 'Coord_Z' an alias name that can be show in attribute table, and for calculated fields I've no idea of what I can do. In this example I show just 3 fields but I have much more in my shapefile. Do you think it is a good idea to use OGR/GDAL or there are some better libraries?

P.S. The raster I need to sample is a DEM

P.P.S. Even if I use the QGIS processing tool "Sample raster values" I've the same problem with alias names and calculated fields

Comment: Use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)( for rasters) and [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) (for shapefiles). They are many examples in GISSE